# Java JFrame - Not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Just trying to make a window with JFrame. It always says "Can't find synbol" for 'new JFrame'

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class window {
    public static void createWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new Jframe("Simple GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
`JFrame` must have a capital "F"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
                    ^---
```

Java is case sensitive. Jframe is not the same as JFrame.

Comment: JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");

Comment: that let me compile the program, now my problem is, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main"

Comment: A Java program needs a main method. If you don't know what a main method is, then you should really learn more before trying to implement a GUI. Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html and follow the tutorial. Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html particularly.

Comment: Instead of "public static void createWindow() {" write "public static void main(String[] args) () {" and do some reading!

Comment: the tutorial tells me to create createWindow() as a method. I did not know that I had to have a main method.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the main method like this

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class window 
{
    public static void createWindow() 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    //set closing bebavior
        frame.setSize(400, 400);                                 //set the size of jframe
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                       //center the jframe 
        frame.setVisible(true);                                  //show the frame
    }
    //main method  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        createWindow();//launch your creaWindow method  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The F in the JFrame can not be lowercased, change it from Jframe to JFrame. And it should work afterwards